# Nonblocking Tcp server

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, nonblocking

It's not a question really, i'm just looking for some guidelines :)
I'm currently writing some abstract tcp server which should use as low number of threads as it can.

Currently it works this way. I have a thread doing listening and some worker threads. Listener thread is just sits and wait for clients to connect I expect to have a single listener thread per server instance. Worker threads are doing all read/write/processing job on clients socket.

So my problem is in building efficient worker process. And I came to some problem I can't really solve yet. Worker code is something like that(code is really simple just to show a place where i have my problem):

```
List<Socket> readSockets = new List<Socket>();
List<Socket> writeSockets = new List<Socket>();
List<Socket> errorSockets = new List<Socket>();

while( true ){
    Socket.Select( readSockets, writeSockets, errorSockets, 10 );

    foreach( readSocket in readSockets ){
        // do reading here
    }

    foreach( writeSocket in writeSockets ){
        // do writing here
    }

    // POINT2 and here's the problem i will describe below 
}
```

it works all smothly accept for 100% CPU utilization because of while loop being cycling all over again, if I have my clients doing send->receive->disconnect routine it's not that painful, but if I try to keep alive doing send->receive->send->receive all over again it really eats up all CPU. So my first idea was to put a sleep there, I check if all sockets have their data send and then putting Thread.Sleep in POINT2 just for 10ms, but this 10ms later on produces a huge delay of that 10ms when I want to receive next command from client socket.. For example if I don't try to "keep alive" commands are being executed within 10-15ms and with keep alive it becomes worse by atleast 10ms :(

Maybe it's just a poor architecture? What can be done so my processor won't get 100% utilization and my server to react on something appear in client socket as soon as possible? Maybe somebody can point a good example of nonblocking server and architecture it should maintain?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener_methods%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class first. It has a BeginAccept method that will not block, and will call one of your functions when someone connects.

Also take a look at the [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket_members%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class and its `Begin` methods. These work the same way. One of your functions (a `callback function`) is called whenever a certain event fires, then you get to handle that event. All the `Begin` methods are asynchronous, so they will not block and they shouldn't use 100% CPU either. Basically you want [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145131%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for reading and [BeginSend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38dxf7kt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for writing I believe.

You can find more on google by searching for these methods and async sockets tutorials. [Here's how](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/AsyncTcpClient.htm) to implement a TCP client this way for example. It works basically the same way even for your server.

This way you don't need any infinite looping, it's all event-driven.

Comment: it would produce a ton of threads, wouldn't it? I'm using loop so I can handle lots of sockets in one thread by reading/writing with a small buffer.

Comment: I suppose it would. Are you sure it's a problem? In any case, can you post your exact code that causes 100% CPU? One idea to avoid it is to have a special "keep-alive" message, something like the server sending "ping?" to the client **every x seconds** and expecting a "pong!" before the next "ping?" should be sent. If it doesn't come, assume a dropped connection. This way you don't have the sleep you're talking about. The keep alive is only done, say, every 60 seconds, not on and on. You could use an AutoResetEvent for example to signal when a keep-alive should be sent, depends on code I think

Comment: @hoodoos You can use TcpListener BeginAccept on a single thread by making your next call to `BeginAccept()` at the end of your AsyncCallback.  You can process one connection fully before listening for another.

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a peer-to-peer application or a client server application? You got to consider how much data you are putting through the sockets as well.

Asynchronous BeginSend and BeginReceive is the way to go, you will need to implement the events but it's fast once you get it right.

Probably don't want to set your Send and Receive timeouts too high as well, but there should be a timeout so that if nothing is receive after a certain time, it will come out of the block and you can handle it there.

Comment: I'm creating server application currently. Finally I'm implemented some abstract worker which is working on abstract protocol chain with phases, and actually I managed to make it work nicely. Now I need to make it handle keep alive connections without eating so much CPU. Currently it handles like 250 concurrent connections. I think I will post code on google, so you can check it out. Thanks. Begin receive/send won't work in my case, since I want to make my application not thread hungry, try to handle 100 concurrent clients on 2 core CPU. you'll see that it eats lots of CPU on context switching

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a nice async TCP server example. It takes a bit to wrap your head around it. It was a few hours of my own time before I was able to create the basic TCP framework for my own program based on this example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

The program logic goes kind of like this. There is one thread that calls listener.BeginAccept and then blocks on allDone.WaitOne. The BeginAccept is an async call which gets offloaded to the threadpool and handled by the OS. When a new connection comes in, the OS calls the callback method passed in from BeginAccept. That method flips allDone to let the main listening thread to know it can listen once again. The callback method is just a transitionary method and continues on to call yet another async call to receive data.

The callback method supplied, ReadCallback, is the primary work "loop"(effectively recursive async calls) for the async calls. I use the term "loop" loosely because each method calls actually finishes, but not before calling the next async method. Effectively, you have a bunch of async calls all calling each other and you pass around your "state" object. This object is your own object and you can do whatever you want with it.

Every callback method will only get two things returned when the OS calls your method:

1) Socket Object representing the connection

2) State object with which you use for your logic

With your state object and socket object, you can effectively handle your "connections" asynchronously. The OS is VERY good at this.

Also, because your main loop blocks waiting for a connection to come it and off-loads those connections to the thread pool via async calls, it remains idle most of the time. The thread pool for your sockets is handled by the OS via completion ports, so they don't do any real work until data comes in. Very little CPU is used and it's effectively threaded via the thread pool.

P.S. From what I understand, you don't want to do any hard work with these methods, just handling the movement of the data. Since the thread pool is the pool for your Network IO and is shared by other programs, you should offload any hard work via threads/tasks/async as to not cause the socket thread pool to get bogged down.

P.P.S. I haven't found a way of closing the listening connection other than just disposing "listener". Because the async call for beginListen is called, that method will never return until a connection comes in, which means, I can't tell it to stop until it returns. I think I'll post a question on MSDN about it. and link if I get a good response.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine is your code exept timeout value. You set it to 10 microseconds (10*10^-6) so your while routine iterates very often. You should set and adequate value (10 seconds for example) and your code will not eat 100% CPU.

```
List<Socket> readSockets = new List<Socket>();
List<Socket> writeSockets = new List<Socket>();
List<Socket> errorSockets = new List<Socket>();

while( true ){
    Socket.Select( readSockets, writeSockets, errorSockets, 10*1000*1000 );

    foreach( readSocket in readSockets ){
        // do reading here
    }

    foreach( writeSocket in writeSockets ){
        // do writing here
    }

    // POINT2 and here's the problem i will describe below 
}
```